# XCode 4.5.1 crash on start up

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can anyone help me with this. It's driving me insane. XCode will start but I can't open projects or start new ones. I've uninstalled Xcode 4.5.1 (from app store) by dragging to the trash but I get the feeling it's not deleting whatever is causing the crash. My macbook is having no problems at all opening the same project files. The first part of the crash report is below. Let me know if I need to paste more.
Any help is very much appreciated
Thanks, Steve

```
Process:         Xcode [497]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5.1 (1842)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1842000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 11278374
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [261]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-10-23 15:12:45.367 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          10165 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  34 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      E08F2BD9-C7A3-6B39-2DAF-D687D853FC1D

Crashed Thread:  23

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000057b00001a10

VM Regions Near 0x57b00001a10:
    MALLOC (reserved)      0000000610000000-0000000800000000 [  7.8G] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  reserved VM address space (unallocated)
--> 
    JS JIT generated code  00002085b4c00000-00002085b4c01000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G1004
objc[497]: garbage collection is ON
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You'd be better off asking on Apple's Xcode users list (https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/xcode-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to beta release of the next version of Xcode fixed this. Either it was a bug with that version, or the update overwrote whatever was causing the problem